# checking UIButton Title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode6

I have a button and title of the button is an integer.

```
correctAnswer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2
button1.setTitle("\(correctAnswer)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I am trying to check the title of the button so convert it to an integer and use it in an if statement, but couldn't make it work.

```
button1.titleLabel?.text?.toInt()
    if button1.titleLabel == correctAnswer { //most probably I am making a mistake here.
        scoring() } else {
        println(button1.titleLabel?.text!)
```

I am new to swift , I might even have problem with my approach, your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you should use `button1.currentTitle`

Comment: I tried it but this gives an error  `button1.currentTitle == correctAnswer`   error is : Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol'_RawOptionSetType'

Comment: then try button1.currentTitle.toInt()! == correctAnswer

Answer (score 3):

also you should use

```
 sender.currentTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using

`sender.titleLabel`

Comment: Can you provide more information? Instead of just a single call, show how the asker would use that call in their code.

Comment: Since this post already had the accepted answer as well as the same solution you provided, it's not preferred to add a new post if there is nothing new.